# Laravel Solarium how to add csv file to Solr core?

Tags: laravel, solr, solarium

I am trying to make a laravel project. Users can upload a csv file to Solr via Laravel. I am already connect solr and can upload a csv file. But i dont know how to add the csv file to solr's core. Any suggestions, what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to index the csv info in Solr you have two options:

- Send the info using a "update" request handler. [More info here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html)
- Use Solarium functions to add documents. [Some examples here](https://gist.github.com/basdenooijer/838598/16ec7866e76c55fd0cb8c0c5e0397d09fe2a3545) and [Solarium Documents documentations here](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/documents/)